What does Dolly do in AE?
Looks like Dolly works like Scale, just increase the size of the object. So, what really does Dolly?


Dolly moves your camera closer to the object.
Scale makes an object bigger. They're not the same thing.

You're writing about the camera, but the Camera layer is not even created. I just turned on the 3D mode.

In that situation where there is no camera, AE just uses your viewpoint. As soon as you add a camera, AE uses that. You'd have more success watching a beginner's guide to AE than asking each question on here piecemeal.

This is old, but it's a great solid understanding of how AE works, and has a section on 3D stuff: https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/

there is one question left, what does dolly to camera poi tool? Adobe writes that there is POI only for two-node cameras. Looks like this option should work only for two-node cameras
